# passing a string from input() to another function, and using np.max function to update np.zeroes array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

can i even use numpy's .max to modify the coordinates of the element with max value? i don't know how to pass the string from the input function to a function that updates the array either.

```
def move_max():
  move_row_index = rewards.max(move_row_index)
  if move_max(w):
    move_row_index -= 1

  rewards.max = move_max(move_row_index, move_column_index)#identify the coordinate using numpy .max built in function
  
max = input('')

print(rewards)
```

...inserted in this code for a q-learning 'AI' from a tutorial. i'm trying to gamify it for interactive input with the q-learning function.

```
import numpy as np
#define the shape of the environment (i.e., its states)
environment_rows = 11
environment_columns = 11

#Create a 3D numpy array to hold the current Q-values for each state and action pair: Q(s, a) 
#The array contains 11 rows and 11 columns (to match the shape of the environment), as well as a third "action" dimension.
#The "action" dimension consists of 4 layers that will allow us to keep track of the Q-values for each possible action in
#each state (see next cell for a description of possible actions). 
#The value of each (state, action) pair is initialized to 0.
q_values = np.zeros((environment_rows, environment_columns, 4))

#define actions
#numeric action codes: 0 = up, 1 = right, 2 = down, 3 = left
actions = ['up', 'right', 'down', 'left']

#Create a 2D numpy array to hold the rewards for each state. 
#The array contains 11 rows and 11 columns (to match the shape of the environment), and each value is initialized to -100.
rewards = np.full((environment_rows, environment_columns), -1.)
rewards[1, 5] = 5. #set the reward for the packaging area (i.e., the goal) to 100

#tutor's code above, mine below
#
#
#
#move the element with max value around the array
def max():
  if input('w'):
    return move_max(w)

def move_max():
  move_row_index = rewards.max(move_row_index)
  if move_max(w):
    move_row_index -= 1

  rewards.max = move_max(move_row_index, move_column_index)#identify the coordinate using numpy .max built in function
  
max = input('')

print(rewards)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean here, but I was working on answering you, and there are too many issues to properly address here. You're writing over your function max() with a variable max, you want to have arguments for your functions, but don't declare them, but then pass them, but don't use them, you're calling functions seemingly in an effort to make a comparison (move_max == "w", but you write move_max(w)). As a result, I can't tell what you are trying to do. Just gotta brush up on the basics.

Comment: thanks for your time, maybe brush up on my etiquette as well. i see your point

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.